# Using Angular Mock Backend resource multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do backend less development in Angular while working disconnected from the backend resources.

Most functionality works fine, but if I try to use any resource a second time I get an error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /localPTicket?ticket=123
No more request expected
```

The scenario I am mocking is one where, for every request to a backend service, I have to first make a Get call to get a valid Proxy Ticket, the response from this is then passed to the next API call.

I have set up a plunker that demonstrates the issue:
 https://plnkr.co/edit/KKa6MXcnbK1gcMiBB7MI?p=preview

I think that the issue is related to flushing the mock requests, but my understanding of the documentation is that using ngMockE2E this should not be an issue.

Thanks for any pointers!

Les

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your are using global regexes.

Global regexes in JavaScript can be very confusing since they have a state. The first time you call it it returns the first match in the string, the second time you call it it returns the next match in the string. If there are no more matches it will return that there were no matches and reset its state.

Simply remove the `g` from the end of your regexes and it should behave as you expect.

Comment: I was looking in the wrong place completely. Learned something new about regex as a bonus.